# Kite Android Studio erro

Tags: kite

Every time I start Android studio I get IDE Fatal errors by a kite.
Exception in plugin Kite AI Code AutoComplete...(1.8.25)

Here is stacktrace.txt :

````
java.lang.Throwable: Can't remove prefix "pid:"
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:146)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.logErrorTestSafe(ProcessListUtil.java:286)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.removePrefix(ProcessListUtil.java:333)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.parseWinProcessListHelperOutput(ProcessListUtil.java:350)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.parseCommandOutput(ProcessListUtil.java:102)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.getProcessListUsingWinProcessListHelper(ProcessListUtil.java:278)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.doGetProcessList(ProcessListUtil.java:43)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.impl.ProcessListUtil.getProcessList(ProcessListUtil.java:35)
    at kite.obfuscated.hk.bg(GenericProcessWatcher.java:33)
    at kite.obfuscated.gy.bg(KiteDetector.java:61)
    at kite.obfuscated.ho.bo(KiteProcessWatcher.java:16)
    at kite.obfuscated.ip.k(KiteProjectLifecycleListener.java:1044)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````